# How can I simultaneously run 3 instances of a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, while-loop, async-await

I have a function called `scan()`. It gets called in a loop. However, how it current works:

1. Calls `scan()`
2. Waits for `scan()` to return
3. Increases `min`
4. Repeat

How can I make it so it runs `2` instances of `scan()` at the same time. Where I can change `2` instances to `3` instances or `4` or `5` etc.

**Example:** How I want it to be (in the below example there are `3` instances of `scan()` running at any one point in time. It should never have more than `3` instances of scan running (with respect to the while loop condition).

Calls `scan()` and waits for return value in the background. Once it gets a return value it increases `min` and calls another instance of `scan()`. There are always `3` instances of `scan()` running (with respect to the while loop condition)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-error" style="display: none"></div>
<form>
  <label for="fname">Fruit (only correct input is: banana)</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fruit-name" name="fruit" value="banana"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="results">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fruitName = $("#fruit-name").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "verify-input.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                fruitName: fruitName
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.code == 200) {
                    $("#submit").html("Running Scan");
                    (async function() {
                        var fruitID = data.fruitId;
                        var min = 1;
                        while (min < 1000) {
                            await scan(fruitID, min, min + 30);
                            min = min + 30;
                        }
                    })();
                } else {
                    $(".display-error").html("<ul>" + data.msg + "</ul>");
                    $(".display-error").css("display", "block");
                }
            }
        });


    });
});

function scan(vFruitId, min, max) {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scanner.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            vFruitId: vFruitId,
            min: min,
            max: max
        },
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach((item, idx) => {
                $("#results").append(`
                <div class="fruit-item" data-item="${idx}">
                    <div class="f-calories">calories: ${item.sweetness}</div>
                    <div class="f-sweetness">sweeteness: ${item.calories}</div>
                    <div class="f-bitterness">bitterness: ${item.bitterness}</div>
                </div><br>
              `);
            })
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

Comment: this is because your scan function does not return any promises

Comment: @MisterJojo , `$.ajax` does return a promise. The issue is that these requests are run synchronously and not concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you want to run concurrently.

```js
//...
while (min < 1000) {
  await scan(fruitID, min, min + 30);
  min = min + 30;
}
//...
```

It's running synchronously at the moment.

There is a library which abstracts some of the complexities of throttling concurrent operations and it's called [promise-throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-throttle).

The implementation would look something along the lines of:

```js
const promiseThrottle = new PromiseThrottle({
    requestsPerSecond: 5, // up to 5 requests per second.. This will adjust the request rate
    promiseImplementation: Promise, // the Promise library you are using
});

const scans = [];
// swapped while loop with for loop but it accomplishes effectively the same task
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i += 30) {
    // closure in order to get correct value of i on each iteration.
    ((min) => {
        scans.push(promiseThrottle.add(() => scan(fruitId, min, min + 30)));
    })(i);
}

Promise.all(scans).then(res => {
    // res is an array of all responses from scans
    // scans completed
});
```

[promise-throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-throttle) does a really nice job abstracting the throttling but the API takes a second to get used to..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using a higher-order function to wrap an existing function:

```
function throttle(max, fn) {
  let queue = [];
  let inProgress = new Set();

  const runTaskNow = async (args) => {
    inProgress.add(args);
    await fn(...args);
    inProgress.delete(args);

    const next = queue.shift();
    if (next) {
      runTaskNow(next.args).then(next.resolve, next.reject);
    }
  };

  const runTaskLater = args => {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((yes, no) => {
      resolve = yes;
      reject = no;
    });
    queue.push({ resolve, reject, args });
    return promise;
  };

  return (...args) => {
    return inProgress.size < max ? runTaskNow(args) : runTaskLater(args);
  }
}
```

To use, wrap your function with `throttle`:

```
const scan = throttle(5, (vFruitId, min, max) => {
  return $.ajax({
    // ...
  });
});
```

...then call it like you'd normally call `scan`.

Comment: so how would i use this actually? like the while loop part? Can you show me my while loop part?

Comment: Also I don't understand how the `scan()` function is supposed to look.